# Mongoose: Querying related object with parameters

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, strapi

Imagine that I have a series of objects related to each other as follows: every object `A`-type has field `b`, that contains id of some instance of object `B`-type.

```
// example of A type
const a = {
  some: 'blablabla',
  b: ObjectId('...')
};

// example of B type
const b = {
  name: 'bla',
  surname: 'blabla'
}
```

**Question**: so, how can I get only those `A`-type instances in which field `b` contains `B-type` object with fields with special values?

For example: get only those instances of `A`-type that has field `some` contains `lorem` and related to `B`-type objects with `name` contains `ipsum`?

**P.S.** I have tried something like this:

```
A.find({ some: 'lorem', 'b.name': 'ipsum' });
```

... but it does not work.

**P.P.S.** I am not a back-end developer at all. But I have no choice :)

Comment: Can you confirm if `b` objects have their own collection or are they saved in the same A collection?

Comment: Hello, Tom. Sorry, it took 2 days to answer.
Yes, I have collection of `a`-items and collection of `b`-items. They are instances of the corresponding models - `A` and `B`. And every instance of `A` model has an id of instance of `b` model.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is is to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) (which is the sql equivalent of `join` if you know that). to "join" the 2 collections. then you can query both objects like so:

```
db.a.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      some: "lorem"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "b",
      "let": {
        "bId": "$b"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$bId",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$name",
                    "ipsum"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "B"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "B.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gqOqeyb0Yph)